# noob at MNIST and I do not know what to look for in the documentation

Tags: tensorflow

I am getting errors like

from: can't read /var/mail/tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist

from: can't read /var/mail/**future**

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add more details in your question in order to expect a good answer. Give a better context around the problem and not just the error message, show what you have tried but has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

From the error messages, it sounds like you are trying to run a TensorFlow program by (i) typing commands into a `bash` (or other command) prompt, or (ii) running it using a command-line interpreter (e.g. by running `source mnist.py`).

To run a TensorFlow Python program, e.g. `tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist.py` you must run it under `python`, by entering the following command at a command-line prompt:

```
python tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist.py
```

Comment: The correct filename will depend on your current directory. e.g. It might be `python mnist.py` if `mnist.py` is in the current directory. What command did you originally type when you got the error in your question?